# Sending Laravel PUSH notifications

Tags: laravel, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send a PUSH notification to my device using Laravel FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) Notification Channel library. I have filled out the configuration in the env file and the token is inserted when sending, but the sending itself does not happen.

```
class FcmNotification extends Notification
{

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return [FcmChannel::class];
    }

    public function toFcm($notifiable)
    {
        try {
        return FcmMessage::create()
            ->setToken('dDH_PSJGR-iIwpLOgsWufE:APA91bH_V_gPwjEcWGxmMbl00Z33eSFV3Zpzc6Sjqb3UlxIwJUtrjlYnBPAvXhx6D6CPMVe9em5UFXZ9kzZlHQrirF0loBdHchBEjVpY_JRi-RNVUQAw3Rok50nayxZLV_uAlHbHzAfG') // Устанавливаем токен устройства в качестве получателя
            ->setNotification(\NotificationChannels\Fcm\Resources\Notification::create()
                ->setTitle('Account Activated')
                ->setBody('Your account has been activated.'))
            ->setAndroid(
                AndroidConfig::create()
                    ->setFcmOptions(AndroidFcmOptions::create()->setAnalyticsLabel('analytics'))
                    ->setNotification(AndroidNotification::create()->setSound('default')));
            }catch (Throwable $e) {
            throw $this->errorHandler->convertException($e);
        }
}
```

When I send it, I receive the following data [image]